# @RequestBody with generic / base request arguments

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have several controllers that extend a BaseController that addresses cross-cutting concerns.

I am now planning to add a new method in BaseController that can provide a common functionality across all controllers.

But the problem is I've different Request and Response objects and I don't know until runtime what @RequestBody parameters are going to be. How can I make it generic so I can handle any type of request objects?

On a side note, all my request and response objects extend a common BaseRequest and BaseResponse objects.

I am using Spring Web 3.1.2 version.

Any advice?